# Adding the "App Groups" entitlement to App ID for Today Extension Widget

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, widget

I am trying to create a widget on the Today extension but have been having some issues regarding entitlements with my provisioning profile.

In essence I'm just trying to output a greeting message on the Today extension. But I am not able to view this message because of what I believe is an entitlements/provisioning profile issue that is preventing the App Groups from being used. I am using XCode 6.1

The error I'm having is below (apologies for all the links; I don't have enough rep points to post inline images it seems)

http://imageshack.com/a/img540/6973/eYBQly.png

And on my Developer Account, you can see that I've enabled App Groups on this App ID

http://imageshack.com/a/img912/3636/jY84SI.png

But it still doesn't seem to work, i.e. I still get the errors pertaining to App Groups not being a part of the App ID which in turn is, I believe, preventing the Today widget from working.

Would someone be able to please explain how the provisioning profile works and what it is that I might be missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Find your App Id and make sure your App Group state is Enabled.
2. Use your App Id to create Provisioning Profiles and download to your computer then double click it
3. Check Xcode's Identity to make sure your team is the right one. If you have problems, click fix issue

Have a look at this link too
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html