# iOS Widget provision profile issue: how to correct distribute with iOS WidgetKit

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, widgetkit

How to correct setting up profile stuff for `iOS Widget` ?

First, I select `auto checkbox`, but distribute app steps get some error. so I try with manual setting to figure out what's going wrong as bellow:

- If I not select a profile for `iOS Widget` target, got error:

> `xxx Widget Extension` required a provision profile with the App Groups feature. ...

- If I select a profile of `iOS Widget` target, got error:

> `xxx Widget Extension` profile is Xcode managed, but signing required a manually managed profile.

#### PS: Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33)

#### *Update 11-22*:

**Provision Profile** is **not the issue** in this case,
I have create a new project with same provision profile & Capability, which I can distribute steps without problem.

**Group Capability** in both Widget Extension & app is setupped.

#### *Update 11-23*:   ************* This Is The Root Cause ***************

When there's a **3rd pod(QuCore-ThirdParty)** included, which can cause distribute step not show `Re-sign` step. [**demo code change**](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/ios_with_widget_extension_demo/compare/3fcfb3d..0acf8f6)

```
 pod 'QuCore-ThirdParty', '3.15.0'
```

#### Works version of Distribute App: [demo code](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/ios_with_widget_extension_demo/tree/dev/works_verison_with_widget_extension_included)

1. Select a method of distribution: [x] App Store Connect
2. Select a destination: [x] Upload
3. App Store Connection distribution options: [x] upload your app's symbols to receive symbolicated reports from Apple
4. `Re-sign "Runner"`: [x] Automatically manage signing

#### Failed version of Distribute App: [demo code](https://github.com/jerryzhoujw/ios_with_widget_extension_demo/tree/dev/failed_to_auto_sign_in_distribute_step)

1. Select a method of distribution: [x] App Store Connect
2. Select a destination: [x] Upload
3. App Store Connection distribution options: [x] Strip Swift symbols [x] upload your app's symbols to receive symbolicated reports from Apple
4. `Select certificate and iOS App Store profile`: Runner.app: [x] xxx  XXXWidgetExtension.appex: [x] xxx

[image]

[image]

Comment: kindly check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636412/adding-the-app-groups-entitlement-to-app-id-for-today-extension-widget

Comment: yes, I have already added group setting in both extension & main app

Comment: Why don't you use *Automatically manage signing* in Xcode?

Comment: Automatic can’t work for me and didn’t tell me any useful information,so I try to use manual to find any further  information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason:

The `bundle id for extension` need to `create manually` on apple's developer website.

If there's a bundle id for extension `created by Xcode`, just `delete` it and manually created one.

Then create `profiles for extension bundle id` manully.

Then it should ok for distribution step.